# Jmeter;Jenkins: Comparing two parsed jtl report to decide build as passes or failed

Tags: jenkins, xml-parsing, jmeter, continuous-integration, performance-testing

How can I parse and compare 2 JTL reports, I am running them via jenkins (as a pipeline job) the first jtl report will act as a base report and the current test run jtl report will be used to compare.The delta between 2 reports can be used as a  % definition to decide the job as success or failure.
currently i am using this stage as a pipeline step to parse the current run jmeter:-

```
performanceReport parsers: [[$class: 'JMeterParser', glob: '/home/jmeter/results/${SERVICE_NAME}/${JMX_NAME}_${TEST_NAME}_*.jtl']], relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 1.2, relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 1.89, relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 1.8, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 1.5
        }
```

The result which I am getting is something like this:-

[jenkins jmeter parsed report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypcr3.jpg)

any idea on how to proceed and achieve this?

Comment: Have you solved? I am interested on the procedure. tks

Answer (score 0):

You can compare current build to previous one or to a reference one. If you have "baseline" report available as Jenkins build #5 and would like to compare the current build to the build #5 - the relevant pipeline syntax would be something like:

```
perfReport modeEvaluation: true, modeOfThreshold: true, nthBuildNumber: 5, percentiles: '0,50,90,100', sourceDataFiles: '/home/jmeter/results/${SERVICE_NAME}/${JMX_NAME}_${TEST_NAME}_*.jtl'
```

References:

- [Performance Plugin: Performance Trends Reporting](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html)
- [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)
- [Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)